# How to use query commands in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

[MongoDb query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXq9D.jpg)

I am new to MongoDB, I just started learning recently.When I am using a query command for instance, db.tests.find({"by":"Srihari"}) .It is not giving any output. Is there any wrong with my query? Please help!

Comment: `db.tests.find({username: "Srihari"})`

Comment: still no luck mate! Please share the syntax. Below is the example I got from tutotialspoints.com db.mycol.find({"by":"tutorials point"}).pretty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you've shared following document exists in your `tests` collection:

```
{"username": "srihari"}
{"username": "srih"}
{"username": "srh"}
{"username": "sh"}
```

The query you're sending to mongodb is :

```
db.tests.find({"by":"Srihari"})
```

There isn't any document in `tests` collection that matches your query.

However, you can query like this:

```
  db.tests.find({"username": "sh"})
```

will definately return the result.

Comment: This terminal works. Can you please check your query as explained above? There seems to be no any document with by:'Srihari'

Comment: yes right! I was using wrong key! Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you specify equality conditions, using `<field>:<value>` expressions in the query filter. So `db.tests.find({"by":"Srihari"})` is looking for all documents where the field "by" has the value "Srihari".
Since your document has the format

```
{
    username: "srihari"
}
```

your query should be:

```
db.tests.find({username: "srihari"})
```

You can see more examples here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/